# Verification Request-Solution in Calculus (Function as an Integral)

Tags: calculus

I need to present a solution to the following problem. I will be glad if someone will check my arguments, since I'm not sure they are correct:
Let $\phi(x) =\int_{x}^{x+1} e^{-t^2} dt $ . 
Where does the function $\phi$ is defined?
Prove that $\phi$ doesn't have an intersection with the $x$ axis.

My attempt:
I wrote $\phi(x)= F(x+1) - F(x)$ ,where $F(x)= \int_0^{x} e^{-t^2} dt $. Then, since the function $e^{-x^2} $ is continous in all $\mathbb{R} $ , we get that $F(x)$ is defined for every $x$ , and in particular $\phi$ is defined for every $x$ .

As for the second question: I was able to prove it using Rolle's theorem, but I am not sure about the following (possible?) way:
$e^{-x^2}$ is continous, and positive. Thus $\int_a^b e^{-x^2} dx $ is strictly positive for every $[a,b]$ and in particular the function $\phi(x)$ is positive. 
Is this argument correct?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your arguments are correct while I prefer this for the second:

As for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $[x,x+1]$ ($x+1>x$) is a closed non empty interval and $e^{-x^2}>0$, $\phi(x)>0$ by the monotonicity of the integral. Note that the fact that $[x,x+1]$ is non-empty is very important and should be emphasised. Consider for example: $f(x)=\int_{0}^xe^{-t^2}dt$ Can the same argument be made in this case?

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot! Got it